# .NET 6 code builds fine for one dev but not others

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, .net-sdk

Our team have seen a few instances recently where code written by one specific dev doesn't build on the other devs' PCs, but we are struggling to figure out why. We all use VS2022, and the solution in question is a .NET 6 WPF application. I'm assuming the problem relates in some way to the .NET 6 SDK versions we're using, but I'm not sure where to check or how to verify this.

Here's one example of such a problem. The dev in question added an interface with `internal` members, along with a concrete implementation were those members were 'public'. This built fine on his PC, yet the rest of us saw this error:

> Property xyz cannot implicitly implement a non-public property from interface IFoobar

Here's another (more obscure) example, which appeared in this method signature:

```
private bool Run(
    Isotope isotope,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(isotope))] string isotopeName = null)
```

Again this code built fine on that one dev's PC, while the rest of us saw this error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'isotope'

(Note, the error was reported on the second argument line).

Thoughts welcome on what the cause might be!

Comment: _"I'm assuming the problem relates in some way to the .Net 6 SDK versions we're using"_ - `dotnet --list-sdks` (from anywhere) and/or `dotnet --version` (from the project folder)

Comment: Note that you can use `global.json` to force concrete SDK (with roll forward rules if needed) to be used.

Comment: Also can you please share the full faulty code (or [mre] representing it)?

Comment: The compiler doesn't change behavior by itself. I'd bet that a newer SDK was installed on that one machine, perhaps during the installation of the latest Visual Studio 2022 version. The *current* LTS version is .NET 8, so that's what gets installed by default. Without `global.json` in the project to restrict the SDK to 6, the code written on that machine would use the latest C# features.

Answer (score 2):

Using `nameof` inside the an attribute on a method or parameter requires at least .NET 7 SDK (though `[CallerArgumentExpression("isotope")]` should work for .NET 6). See the [Extended `nameof` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/extended-nameof-scope) feature spec for C# 11.

By default [the latest installed SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version) is used so if the newer language feature has not required changes in the CLR the project should compile and run successfully. It seems that the developer has .NET 7 or .NET 8 SDK installed (run `dotnet --list-sdks` to check).

You can check the SDK version used to build the project by running `dotnet --version` from the project folder.

Note that you can force the same SDK version to be used for build by adding [`global.json` file to project/solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/global-json). For example the following will force the same major version:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

Also possibly restricting [C# language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) used to C# 10 will do the trick also.

Comment: On the dev's PC where such code builds, `dotnet --version` reports 7.0.2, whereas on my PC (where it does *not* build) it reports 8.0.1. As you say I could understand if he was on a higher version, but not lower?! We'll give the two other suggestions a try shortly (restricting SDK version and C# version) and report back.

Comment: Using Directory.build.props on his PC to restrict to C# 10.0 had no effect and the solution still builds.

Comment: Neither of us have SDK v6 installed so we can't try the global.json idea. I guess I had assumed we were all using v6, seeing as the solution's projects target .Net 6 (due to my lack of understanding as explained in @Ian Kemp's answer).

Comment: @AndrewStephens then you need to create a [mre] and provide full compilation error texts so we can try to help you. Also VS versions.

Comment: @AndrewStephens also what if you try to compile the code with `dotnet build`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common confusion caused by the fact that there are actually two version numbers that you need to know about when compiling a piece of C# code. The first is the most obvious - the SDK version being used for the compilation, specified by the `<TargetFramework>` tag in the project file. This specifies the *minimum runtime version* that the code will be compiled against and be able to run on.

However there is a second, equally important, version number: that of the actual C# language version being used to compile that code. This `<LangVersion>` tag determines *what C# features are allowed to be present* in the file being compiled.

The reason for this two-layered approach is that many newer C# language features are actually [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that are *transformed during compilation* to something that older runtimes can understand. For example, [the `nameof` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) that was introduced in C# 6, is transformed into a constant string at runtime, such that e.g. `nameof(something)` becomes `"something"`. Since constant strings have been a fundamental runtime feature since the original version of the .NET Framework, a C# program using `nameof` and no other newer language features would compile to something that an ancient .NET Framework 1.0 runtime would happily execute. The .NET team felt that it didn't make sense to restrict useful syntactic sugar features to a specific SDK, therefore they introduced `LangVersion` as a way to allow developers targeting older runtimes to benefit from such features.

Note that the SDK-language version relationship works only one way. That is, a newer SDK can compile programs using language versions <= the version that SDK supports, but an older SDK cannot compile code using language features it does not know about.

So what should you and your team do? My suggestion would be to [follow Microsoft's guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#configure-multiple-projects) and use a `Directory.Build.props` file in the root of your project's repository with a specific maximum language version (a table of these versions can be found on that page) that you want your developers to write C# code in (and ensuring that all developers have an SDK version installed that supports that langver). That way, if a dev tries to use a newer C# feature that others may not support, they will get a compile-time error *on their machine* and should never check that code in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've never really got my head around this kind of thing (and never had to until now!). Please see my comments to Guru Stron as to what we have found and tried so far.